# Messy output and terminal in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've been experiencing a whole of clutter in the terminal when I run programs in Python.
Example:

```
PS C:\Users\danhe\AppData\Roaming\Code> & C:/Users/danhe/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe "c:/Users/danhe/OneDrive/Desktop/Python projects/22222222.py"
Hello, world
PS C:\Users\danhe\AppData\Roaming\Code>
```

I tried using code runner to display the output but get a similar problem:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\danhe\OneDrive\Desktop\Python projects\22222222.py"
Hello, world

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.267 seconds
```

I don't know how other people got the dollar sign or nothing and I get all this crap.  It's hard to stay organized with all the clutter and has made me turn to Jupyter notebook exclusively for self-teaching.

A dozen online tutorials and many google searches and none address my problem.

Comment: Welcome to [so].  It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing what you are doing and what execution environment which produces your problem. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and the relevant steps necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Format code, input and output properly (as code).

Comment: at last you have the output you expect, a lot of users don't even get that far, do all your python programs only output 1 line, the once I write for AOC do, some output nothing but just change some files, and who  cares what the command is during developing, in production you can do it how you want

Comment: Do you mean the shell prompts and the path to `python.exe`? You can probably configure your shell to use different prompts (bash uses a $, for example). The details depend on your shell, and a quick web search will find a lot of tutorials. You can add `python.exe` to your `PATH` so that you don't have to specify the full path; however, your IDE may always use the full path so that it's clear what is getting used, in case you have different Python versions installed. `[Running]` and `[done]` probably also come from your IDE. Just ignore it, or check if your IDE can be told to skip it.

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the clutter you're seeing in the terminal when running Python scripts (You are on Windows if Im right) is related to the command prompt's default behavior.

You can improve the readability and organization of your terminal by changing your terminal prompt.

The "PS" and other information at the beginning of your terminal prompt is specific to Windows PowerShell. You can customize your prompt to make it cleaner. You can do this by modifying your PowerShell profile.

For example:

```
function prompt {
    "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)> "
}
```

Save this script in your PowerShell profile. To edit your profile, run notepad $PROFILE in PowerShell and add the function. This will change your prompt to something like `PS C:\Your\Current\Directory>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Code Runner**, adding the following settings will give you clean results in **OUTPUT**:

```json
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
```